# Difference between Thymeleaf include and replace?

Tags: thymeleaf

What is the difference between the two Thymeleaf attributes: `th:include` and `th:replace`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html) if you have this situation:

```
<div th:include="..."> content here </div>
```

fragment will be placed inside `<div>` tag.

However when you use replace:

```
<div th:replace="..."> content here </div>
```

then `<div>` will be replaced by content.

> Thymeleaf can include parts of other pages as fragments (whereas JSP
>   only includes complete pages) using th:include (will include the
>   contents of the fragment into its host tag) or th:replace (will
>   actually substitute the host tag by the fragment’s).

Comment: Since 3.0, th:include is not recommended (see http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#difference-between-thinsert-and-threplace-and-thinclude)

Answer (score 6):

Taken from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-fragments)

There are three basic ways to include content from a fragment:

- insert – inserts content inside the tag
- replace – replaces the current tag with the tag defining the fragment
- include – this is deprecated but it may still appear in a legacy code

Answer (score 6):

Try to understand with this 
suppose this the fragment

```
<div th:fragment="targetFragmentToIncludeInOurPage" id="tagWithFragmentAttribute">
 <div id="contentGoesHere"></div>
</div>
```

we are using this in these div

```
<div id="tagWithReplaceAttribute" th:replace="fragments/header :: targetFragmentToIncludeInOurPage"></div>
<div id="tagWithInsertAttribute" th:insert="fragments/header :: targetFragmentToIncludeInOurPage"></div>
<div id="tagWithIncludeAttribute" th:include="fragments/header :: targetFragmentToIncludeInOurPage"></div>
```

So the final output:

```
<div id="tagWithFragmentAttribute">
 <div id="contentGoesHere"></div>
</div>

<div id="tagWithInsertAttribute">
 <div id="tagWithFragmentAttribute">
  <div id="contentGoesHere"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="tagWithIncludeAttribute">
 <div id="contentGoesHere"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Thymeleaf` can include parts of other pages as fragments (whereas `JSP` only includes complete pages) using `th:include` (will include the contents of the fragment into its host tag) or `th:replace` (will actually substitute the host tag by the fragment’s). This allows the grouping of fragments into one or several pages.